# Calculate Haversine distance in R

Tags: r, google-maps, distance, ggmap

I am using the *geosphere* library in R to calculate the haversine distance between two countries. I am using the following code to get the lat/long of each country using the geonames API and then passing them onto the *distHaversine* function to get the distance:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  row<-df[i,]

  start<-GNsearch(q=row$Address.Country, maxRows=1, adminCode1='00')
  start_lng<-as.numeric(start$lng)
  start_lat<-as.numeric(start$lat)


  end<-GNsearch(q=row$Country.Value, maxRows=1, adminCode1='00')
  end_lng<-as.numeric(end$lng)
  end_lat<-as.numeric(end$lat)


  print(i)
  print(c(row$Address.Country, start_lng, start_lat))
  print(c(row$Country.Value, end_lng, end_lat))


  df[i,]$dist<-distHaversine( p1=c(start_lng, start_lat), p2=c(end_lng, end_lat) )

  print(df[i,]$dist)

}
```

However, the function *distHaversine* is returning *NULL* and I am getting the output that looks like:

```
[1] 224
[1] "United States" "-98.5"         "39.76"        
[1] "Mexico" "-102"   "23"    
NULL
```

Where am I going wrong?

**UPDATE**

I think the problem is that despite using *as.numeric* the long/lat pair is not getting converted to numeric. I tried looking around for the solution, and even tried using

```
as.numeric(as.character(end$lng))
...
```

But, that also does not seem to work!

**UPDATE 2**

In response to SymbolixAU, here is a sample of the dataset:

```
dput(head(df))
structure(list(Country.Value = c("United States", "Brasil", 
"United States", "India", "China", "Denmark"), Address.Country = c("United States", 
"United States", "United States", "Romania", "United States", 
"France"), .Names = c("Country.Value", "Address.Country", 
"Award.Date"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x00000000001f0788>)
```

**UPDATE 3**

I have further updated the code to try and incorporate *Google Maps geocoder* instead of *geonames* as *geonames* was quite inaccuarte in some places. I have also used if-else statements to try and stay within the geocoding limits set by the free *Google Maps geocoder*. The code now is as follows:

```
for(i in q:nrow(df)) {
  row<-df.cont.long[i,]

  src_lon<- 0.0
  src_lat<- 0.0
  trgt_lon<- 0.0
  trgt_lat<- 0.0  


  if((row$Country.Value=='United States')){  #Reduce geocoding requirements
    trgt_lon<- -95.7129
    trgt_lat<- 37.0902
  }
  else if((row$Address.Country=='United States')){  #Reduce Geocoding Requirements
    src_lon<- -95.7129
    src_lat<- 37.0902
  }
  else if((row$Country.Value=='Canada')){  #Reduce geocoding requirements
    trgt_lon<- -106.3468
    trgt_lat<- 56.1304
  }
  else if((row$Primary.Address.Country=='Canada')){  #Reduce Geocoding Requirements
    src_lon<- -106.3468
    src_lat<- 56.1304
  }
  else if(row$Country.Value == row$Address.Country){   #Reduce Geocoding Requirements
    # trgt<-geocode(row$Country.Value)
    # trgt_lon<-as.numeric(trgt$lon)
    # trgt_lat<-as.numeric(trgt$lat)
    # src_lon<-as.numeric(trgt$lon)
    # src_lat<-as.numeric(trgt$lat)
  }
  else{
    trgt<-geocode(row$Country.Value, output=c("latlon"))
    trgt_lon<-as.numeric(trgt$lon)
    trgt_lat<-as.numeric(trgt$lat)

    src<-geocode(row$Address.Country)
    src_lon<-as.numeric(src$lon)
    src_lat<-as.numeric(src$lat)

  }

  print(i)
  print(c(row$Address.Country, src_lon, src_lat))
  print(c(row$Country.Value, trgt_lon, trgt_lat))

  print(distHaversine( p1=c(as.numeric(src$lon), as.numeric(src$lat)), p2=c(as.numeric(trgt$lon), as.numeric(trgt$lat)) ))


}
```

The output now is even more erratic:

```
[1] 993
[1] "United States" "0"             "0"            
[1] "United States" "-95.7129"      "37.0902"      
[1] NA
[1] 994
[1] "United States" "-95.7129"      "37.0902"      
[1] "Brazil" "0"      "0"     
[1] NA
[1] 995
[1] "United States" "-95.7129"      "37.0902"      
[1] "Mexico" "0"      "0"     
[1] NA
[1] 996
[1] "United States" "-95.7129"      "37.0902"      
[1] "Bolivia" "0"       "0"      
[1] NA
[1] TRUE
[1] 997
[1] "South Africa" "0"            "0"           
[1] "South Africa" "0"            "0"           
[1] NA
[1] 998
[1] "United States" "-95.7129"      "37.0902"      
[1] "Costa Rica" "0"          "0"         
[1] NA
[1] 999
[1] "United States" "-95.7129"      "37.0902"      
[1] "Tanzania" "0"        "0"       
[1] NA
[1] 1000
[1] "United States" "-95.7129"      "37.0902"      
[1] "Greece" "0"      "0"     
[1] NA
[1] 1001
[1] "United States" "-95.7129"      "37.0902"      
[1] "Namibia" "0"       "0"      
[1] NA
.Information from URL : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Colombia&sensor=false
.Information from URL : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=United%20Kingdom&sensor=false
[1] 1002
[1] "United Kingdom" "-3.435973"      "55.378051"     
[1] "Colombia"   "-74.297333" "4.570868"  
[1] 8398813
[1] 1003
[1] "United States" "-95.7129"      "37.0902"      
[1] "Guatemala" "0"         "0"        
[1] 8398813
```

In the output

1. Sometimes geocoding is done, sometimes not, and is defaulting to 0.0
2. Sometimes distance is getting calculated, sometimes not

I have no idea where the code is going wrong.

Comment: Are you mixing up src with start, trgt with end?

Comment: `distHaversine(p1=c(-98.5, 39.76), p2 = c(-102, 23))` seems to work fine. I'd guess it's to do with your `start_lng`/`start_lat` etc variables.

Comment: @mdsummer: I corrected the typo. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: can you provide an example of the data sets you're using so others can reproduce your issue? use `dput(head(df))`